# Does Serilog JsonFormatter support Formatting.Indented?

Tags: c#, logging, json.net, serilog

I have code like this

```
        var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails()
            .WriteTo.RollingFile(new JsonFormatter(renderMessage: true),"log-{Date}.txt")                
            .CreateLogger();
```

Is it possible to format the Json result as **Indented** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; the JSON formatter's goal is to produce newline-delimited JSON streams for consumption by other programs - human readability isn't a primary consideration.

You can, however, pipe these through something like `jq` to pretty-print it:

```
cat log-20170420.txt | jq '.'
```

(`chocolatey install jq` or `sudo apt-get install jq` depending on your OS.)

Comment: Can I replace serilog jsonformatter with json.net for achieving that ? if yes how ?

Comment: There's nothing out-of-the-box; custom formatters are possible but take some work (see, for example, https://github.com/serilog/serilog-formatting-compact).